# How to configure HAProxy to pass though unencoded URL to Jenkins backend?

Tags: haproxy, jenkins

I have HAProxy configured to terminate SSL connections for a Jenkins CI server, proxying to the Jenkins CI server backend over plain ol' HTTP. I can successfully perform [thus far] all of the operations I need to in the Jenkins CI server web interface, including manage the instance.

However, I get [the Jenkins "reverse proxy setup is broken" warning](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken). This is caused by stricter proxy configuration checking since Jenkins version 1.572, which uses a URL in the form of:

```
https://host-name/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/a%2Fb/
```

to test the reverse proxy configuration. The typical cause for the warning called out is the decoding of the `%2F` into a forward slash by the reverse proxy, which causes a 404.

There seems to be well documented configuration solutions for Apache and nginx reverse proxy configurations to eliminate this warning. What I have not been able to find is something similar to Apache's "AllowEncodedSlashes On" option, or nginx's "proxy_pass" configuration, or even an example of setting up Jenkins behind HAProxy (which I'm using instead of Apache or nginx because we already have HAProxy in place for other applications).

- Operating system: CentOS 6.6
- HAProxy version:  1.5.2-2
- Jenkins version:  1.610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not, as it turned out, an issue with the URL encoding / decoding. It was simply operator error on my part - when terminating SSL at any proxy you ***must*** ensure that the **X-Proxy-Proto** header is set to **https** so that all URLs generated by Jenkins in this manner get use a scheme of **https**. I missed the line in the documentation on the troubleshooting page. Simple adding:

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

To the backend definition removed the warning.